# Does two mentioned syntax differentiate in 'on' function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know what is the difference between below two syntax?

1:

```
$('#highlights').on(
    'click', 'li', function(){
        var id = this.id;
        var url = $(this).data('imgurl');
        alert(url);
    }
);
```

2:

```
$('#highlights li').on(
    'click', function(){
        var id = this.id;
        var url = $(this).data('imgurl');
        alert(url);
    }
```

);

Comment: The first one (delegated event) is like saying "Every time #highlighs is clicked check if a `li` has been clicked, if so, run this". The second one is like saying "If this `li` is clicked run this" multiple times for every `li`

Comment: https://tutsplus.com/lesson/bind-live-delegate-huh/

Comment: To expand on @DavidFregoli, the run-time difference is in who handles the event, and what "this" is set to.  In the first, the click event is bound to #highlights, so $(this) would be the #highlights element.  In the second, the click event is bound to the LI in #hightlights, and as a result $(this) would be the LI element.  I use the first a lot when I need to do something on a parent element as a result of some action at a child level so I don't have to traverse up the DOM tree just to go down, for instance when I have tables where a button in the table adds a row to the end.

Comment: @CodeChimp actually `this` will refer to `li` in both cases!

Comment: Your absolutely right!  I know I have used this before, but I guess I am mistaken on how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one will work for *any* li that is in the #highlights element, the second one will work for any li that was in the #highlights element when the click function was bound.  I.e. - if I use jquery to do:

```
 $('#highlights li').on('click', function(){
    var id = this.id;
    var url = $(this).data('imgurl');
    alert(url);
});

$('#highlights').append('<li>click this</li>');
```

If I click that new element, nothing will happen.  With the first one it would still work.

Comment: also, the second one is heavier (especially if you have tons of `li` elements) since it binds an event listener to every `li`. The first one only binds one event to the `#highliths` element

Answer (score 1):

The first method will work for elements appended to the DOM after the event handler is bound, similar to how `live` was once used.  The second will not attach the event handler to elements appended to the DOM, but will work for elements present when the DOM is loaded.

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/FhpJp/1/